# detect select value with jquery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to utilize the JQuery if statement to create a form that will allow employees to create a custom verbal script for their customers. Basically the JQuery Plugin will simply append input field values to a dialogue to be read by the employee to the customers.

I've had no issue with the JS written to append the contents of text-fields and select boxes to the dialogue but seem to be unable to figure out the most crucial part. I want to be able to show or hide information relevant to specific states based upon the value of a select box input field.

Below is a single example of my attempt at utilizing the if/else statement to do so.

HTML:

```
<select name="state_select" class="state_select">
       <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
</select>

<p class="ct_opt">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Css:

```
.ct_opt {
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($("select.state_select").val() == "CT") {
    $("ct_opt").show();

} else {

    if ($("select.state_select").val() != "CT")
        $("ct_opt").hide();
    }
});
```

From what I understand, this should allow the targeted text to stay hidden unless its corresponding state is selected. However, it seems to do nothing at the current moment :(

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need if condition within else block...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ct_opt` because it's a class and execute your code when selection changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.state_select").change(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == "CT") 
          $(".ct_opt").show();
       else $(".ct_opt").hide();
    });
    $("select.state_select").change(); //call change event when page loads
});
```

You can use $() because it's equivalent to document ready:

```
$(function(){
    $("select.state_select").change(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == "CT") 
          $(".ct_opt").show();
       else $(".ct_opt").hide();
    });
    $("select.state_select").change(); //call change event when page loads
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.state_select').val('CT');
    $('.state_select').on('change', function() {
        console.log('click');
        if($(this).val() == 'CT') {
            $('.ct_opt').show();
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'noshow') {
            $('.ct_opt').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="state_select" class="state_select">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="noshow">Dont Show</option>
</select>

<p class="ct_opt">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('select.state_select')` will select an *array* of select objects with the class `state_select`.  If you only have one state_select you should change this selector to `$('#state_select')`.  There is no point in using `$('select#state_select')` (although valid) since there can only be a single id per page.  You *could* use your current selector but you will need to call `.first()` to get the first item in the array of elements matching that selector.

Additionally as Ragnar pointed out there is no element named 'ct_opt' so you  need to change your selector to $('.ct_opt') to target the class.